# Efficient passing vector to setter in class

Tags: c++, c++14

I have class:

```
class Example
{
  const std::vector<int>& getMyVector() { return myVector; }
  //void setMyVector 
private:
  std::vector<int> myVector;
}

void methodCreatingNewMyVector(Example& example)
{
  std::vector<int> newMyVector;
  //some push_backs
  example.setMyVector(newMyVector);
}
```

How to implement setMyVector method to not copy vector and use temporary vector from above method? I do not want to use smart pointers to store myVector. Can I use move semantics? How to do this?

Comment: std::move comes to mind.

Comment: Why not `example.getMyVector()` and then work directly with the target vector inside `methodCreatingNewMyVector` ?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot add const go getMyVector()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just provide a `setMyVector()` overload taking an rvalue reference to the `std::vector<int>` and move the object there, e.g.:

```
void setMyVector(std::vector<int>&& newVector) {
    this->myVector = std::move(newVector);
}
```

Obviously, you'd call this function appropriately:

```
example.setMyVector(std::move(newMyVector));
```

Comment: hello, can you tell me why do you need to make the parameter reference to reference?

Comment: @LorenceHernandez: the `&&` isn't a "reference to a reference" but rather an *rvalue reference*. A comment is probably a bit terse to introduce C++ move semantics but the basic idea is that you cannot bind an lvalue (i.e., something you can somehow refer to ) to an rvalue reference. You *can* bind temporaries or lvalues made look like temporaries (e.g., using `std::move()`) to an rvalue reference. The upshot is: an rvalue reference indicates that the object it refers to is about to go away and the representation can be transferred. This overload of `setMyVector()` transfers the representation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can explicitly *move* the vector without copying it by calling [`std::move()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move). This casts your vector to an rvalue reference, the `std::vector` constructor has a specialized constructor to take advantage of this type:

```
example.setMyVector(std::move(newMyVector));
```

Make sure to ask for an rvalue reference in `setMyVector()` :

```
void setMyVector (std::vector<int> && vec)
                                   ^^rvalue reference
```

Comment: if setMyVector doesn't take the argument as an R-value ref that std::move won't do much

Comment: @RyanP: actually, `setMyVector()` can also take the argument by value which *is* a decent idea as it can avoid copy/moves due to copy elision. However, for something like the above class I'd rather have a special lvalue assignment potentially reusing existing memory.